# Need to Display Admob Ad Through MoPub

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, mopub

I want to display an `admob Ad` Through `mopub sdk` in one of my iPhone application but i am not able to find the `API Password` And `API Key` through Ad Mob.

Can anyone please help me to integrate Admob network in mopub account?

Comment: were you able to display admit thru mopub?

Answer (score 0):

API Password and API Key are for the Legacy AdMob integration and are now deprecated. Please use OAuth for Network Revenue Reporting.

You should still be able to display AdMob ads even though Network Revenue Reporting is not enabled on MoPub.

I'd reach out to MoPub Support if you have any issues.

Edward

Comment: Thanks. but can't get success through OAuth.

Comment: You have to be logged into your Google account associated with your AdMob account for OAuth to work. Please make sure that this is the case when requesting OAuth.